# How can I convert json-api-normalizer data into a format digestible by Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, activerecord, normalization, json-api

I'm building a React app but am struggling with the best practices around data formats.

I'd like to do the following:

1. Give my react app seed data in JSON API format
2. Convert JSON API data with json-api-normalizer and put into Redux store (json-api-normalizer much more suitable to Redux modifications)
3. Modify my Redux store, and submit this data back to my Rails app to be processed by Active Record.

The Problem:

The [json-api-normalizer](https://github.com/yury-dymov/json-api-normalizer) data format is not in a structure that ActiveRecord will process. How can I convert json-api-normalizer data format (either on the front end or back end) into something that AR will process? Ideally I'm looking for a library here, before resorting to rolling my own solution. This seems like a situation that wouldn't be ucommon.

Comment: Can you show us what the data looks like?  I picture you needing something like this.  https://github.com/chrokh/normalizr , but I imagine that it is way more complicated.

Comment: @zakariah1 the link you references normalizes data. My data is already normalized. It basically needs to be denormalized from json-api-normalizer format to Active Record.